# Squarespace/Google Sheets API data changing order?

Tags: google-sheets, squarespace

I'm using Apipheny to import some data into a google sheet that I'm then referencing in another sheet to do accounting math. The problem is, every time my API call runs (once an hour), it seems like the order of the data is changing?

I have to keep going in and changing the columns being pulled in order to keep the calculations working correctly.

API call:

```
https://api.squarespace.com/1.0/commerce/orders
```

This pulls all data for all orders into a sheet.

Query I'm using to pull data to another sheet:

```
=QUERY((Data!B2:BA), "Select Col1,Col28,Col36,Col37 WHERE (Col28 like '%HFM')")
```

The columns I select keep moving around, usually 1 or 2 values bot last night I had to move them about 8. Sometimes, Columns 36 and 37 just switch.

Any help would be great! I'm not well-versed in API stuff and kinda figuring this out as I go, but I've been unable to find any info about this online.

I've tried referring to columns differently to keep the calculation sheet functioning, but it hasn't worked.
The end goal is for data to be pulled in to the Sheets doc in the same column order each time, rather than shuffling around at random. We use a second sheet in this document to pull in specific pieces of data & calculate values from the results.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Squarespace API or Apipheny. If this is not something you can control via Apipheny, then I might suggest looking up the data values via an `index + match` to grab data by column header match in your second sheet (where you are currently doing the query).